# What are the differences between Worms HD and Worms 2: Armageddon?

Tags: ios, version-differences, worms-2-armageddon, worms-2007

What are the differences between these two versions for the iPad?

I've heard that *Worms 2: Armageddon* doesn't have multiplayer mode when several players are using one device. But I need this feature. Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

Worms 2 Armageddon does have multiplayer for up to 3 players. The biggest difference between Worms 2 and Worms HD are the upgraded visuals in Worms HD.

Worms 2 defiantly has a campaign mode whereas I don't think Worms HD has, I think Worms HD only has a series of challenges and skirmish mode.

I provided two links for both the apps at the apple store, click the "...more" on the right to get the details.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/worms-hd/id363503154?mt=8#

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/worms-2-armageddon/id355524910?mt=8#